# How to find $\int \frac{x^4-4}{x^2\sqrt{4+x^2+x^4}} \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $$\int \frac{(x^4-4)}{(x^2\sqrt{4+x^2+x^4})}\mathrm dx$$

---

My try:
$$\int \frac{(x^2-4/x^2)}{(\sqrt{4+x^2+x^4})}\mathrm dx\\
=\int \frac{ (x^2-4/x^2)}{(\sqrt{(x^2+1/2)^2+15/4})}\mathrm dx\\$$
Let $t=x^2$
$$=\int \frac{(t^2-4)}{2t\sqrt t\sqrt{(t+1/2)^2+15/4}}\mathrm dt=?$$

---

Answer:Spoiler

> $$\frac{\sqrt{4+x^2+x^4}}{x}$$

Comment: Given that Maxima finds no answer, and Wolfram integrator yields [this](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=%28x^2-4%29%2F%28x^2*Sqrt[4%2Bx^2%2Bx^4]%29&random=false), I am rather pessimistic regarding the possibility to find an answer with only elementary functions.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut this has a closed form without involving any elementary function beyond squareroots, from my textbook for highschool

Comment: @AhaanRungta see my above comment

Comment: There is also something wrong in your change of variable: $\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{2\sqrt t}$, so there should be a $\sqrt{t}$ appearing somewhere.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Good point.

Comment: You may consider reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), that will explain why you should not expect too much: such integrals with the square root of a poly of degree at most 2 are rather easy, but with degree 3 or 4, not so.

Comment: @Aditya and what is the solution in textbook?

Comment: @monhawk I hesitate telling it early, when not much times has passed, Sorry please wait, you'll be surprised to see such an easy answer

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Elliptic Integrals are not in my course

Comment: @Aditya If you have the answer, you can at least check that there is no typo by differentiating it.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yeah I checked at wolfram

Comment: differentiating your answer gives a different result: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+%28%284%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%5E4%29%5E%281%2F2%29%29%2Fx

Comment: I went about the reverse way. I differentiated the answer you provided and it produced: $$\int \frac{(x^4-4)dx}{x^2 \sqrt{x^4+x^2+4}}$$

Are you sure there isn't a printing mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\int \frac{(x^4-4)dx}{(x^2\sqrt{4+x^2+x^4})}$$ 
$$ \int \frac{(x^2-4x^{-2})dx}{(\sqrt{4+x^2+x^4})} $$
$$  \int \frac{(x-4x^{-3})dx}{(\sqrt{4x^{-2}+1+x^2})} $$
Take, $$ u = 1+x^2+4x^{-2} \implies du = (2x-8x^{-3})dx \implies du/2 = (x-4x^{-3})dx$$ 
So integral = 
$$ \int \frac{du/2}{\sqrt{u}} = \sqrt{u} + C \implies \frac{\sqrt{4+x^4+x^2}}{x} +C $$